# Overriding type from base class that conformed from associatedtype

Tags: swift, generics

Lets say i have this class:

```
protocol GenericViewModel {
  associatedtype Model
  associatedtype ViewModel
}

class BaseVc: GenericViewModel {

typealias Model = ModelA
typealias ViewModel = ViewModelA
var baseVm:ViewModel<Model>

}
```

now i want to extend base vc with other types for the baseVm property

```
class AwesomeVc: BaseVc {

typealias Model = ModelB
typealias ViewModel = ViewModelB

}
```

the expected result would be that when i type `viewModel` i should see the compiler recognize `ViewModelB`, in practice i see that there is no way to "`override`" the value specified in the base class.

how can i achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Is `BaseVc` supposed to conform to `GenericViewModel`?

Comment: What you are trying to do here breaks inheritance. `AwesomeVc` inherits `BaseVc`. so you can't have `baseVm` to be of one type in `BaseVc`, and another type in `AwesomeVc`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, edited

Comment: i need to have the type dynamic in each class that inherits from BaseVC

Comment: Then they should _not_ inherit from `BaseVC` because that's not how inheritance works. They should be classes on their own, or share a common interface with `BaseVC`.